# How the Arrays.sort works after the Comparable interface is done in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, comparable

The code is to sort the and print students name according to their marks in descending order. In a class there are ‘n’ number of students. They have three different subjects: Data Structures, Algorithm Design & Analysis and Operating Systems. Marks for each subject of all the students are provided to you. You have to tell the position of each student in the class. Print the names of each student according to their position in class. Tie is broken on the basis of their roll numbers. Between two students having same marks, the one with less roll number will have higher rank. The input is provided in order of roll number.
I am able to implement the code in which I made a pair class to sort according to their marks and stored all the object in the array. After that I used Array.sort to sort the array.
So how did the Arrays.sort(pair) sorted the array on what basis.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main{
    static class pair implements Comparable<pair>{
        int marks;
        String name;
        public pair(int m, String n){
            this.marks = m;
            this.name = n;
        }
        @Override
        public int compareTo(pair p){
            return p.marks - this.marks;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        // String sn = in.nextLine();
        int n = in.nextInt();
        pair[] arr= new pair[n];
        for(int i =0;i< n;i++){
            String name = in.next();
            int sum = 0;
            for(int j = 0;j<3;j++){
                int num = in.nextInt();
                sum += num;
            }
            int marks = sum ;
            arr[i]= new pair(marks,name);
        }
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        for(int i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){
            System.out.println(i+1 +" "+arr[i].name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need post some code for other people help you.You can see this for ask a good question[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I was unable to put the code here as there was some issue with formatting and stackoverflow was not letting me do so.

Comment: You just post the code,i can help you reformat the code.

Comment: Hi, I included the code.

Answer (score 0):

In the below code comparator is doing compare on basis of marks. Array.sort uses a customized comparator.

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

class Student {
    int rollno, marks;
    String name;

    public Student(int rollno, int marks, String name) {
        this.rollno = rollno;
        this.name = name;
        this.marks = marks;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.rollno + " " + this.name + " " + this.marks;
    }
}

class Sortbymarks implements Comparator<Student> {
    public int compare(Student a, Student b) {
        return b.marks - a.marks;
    }
}

public class ArraySort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student[] arr = { new Student(111, 150, "abc"), new Student(131, 100, "abcd"), new Student(121, 120, "xyz"),
                new Student(191, 150, "txy") };

        System.out.println("Unsorted");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            System.out.println(arr[i]);

        Arrays.sort(arr, new Sortbymarks());

        System.out.println("Sorted by marks");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I think the solution is fine but we will not take input of roll number. Roll number will be decided according to as they are taken in the input. Here is my code.
I was able to code but the thing I want to ask is how Arrays.sort() organise the whole object in the array if we have already sorted all the object using comparator. Wish I could enter my code here but I am unable to do so as it is not able to take that much long answer

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is my answer. I want to know how Arrays.sort() sorts the object pair after it has already been sorted according to their marks.
import java.util.*;
public class Main{
    static class pair implements Comparable<pair>{
        int marks;
        String name;
        public pair(int m, String n){
            this.marks = m;
            this.name = n;
        }
        @Override
        public int compareTo(pair p){
            return p.marks - this.marks;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        // String sn = in.nextLine();
        int n = in.nextInt();
        pair[] arr= new pair[n];
        for(int i =0;i< n;i++){
            String name = in.next();
            int sum = 0;
            for(int j = 0;j<3;j++){
                int num = in.nextInt();
                sum += num;
            }
            int marks = sum ;
            arr[i]= new pair(marks,name);
        }
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        for(int i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){
            System.out.println(i+1 +" "+arr[i].name);
        }
    }
}
```